# Were there philosophers who were against music?

Tags: music

There are sayings from Socrates and Confucius, showing they had great respect of music. But were there philosophers who had the opposite views toward music?

Comment: While Plato was not altogether against music, he did insist that it be played in two only modes, which he considered character building;  Ionian and Dorion.

Comment: it depends on how you define "philosopher". There are many religious figures around the world who consider certain types of music to be evil or of the devil...

Comment: @niels nielsen any philosopher who don't prohibit music because of religious taboos.

Comment: Adorno famously hated the jazz music of his era. But he was, I think, also into twelve-tone serialism, so maybe an odd example... You might find *The Dialectic of Pop* interesting.